# Can I implement a gradient descent for arbitrary convex loss function?

Tags: numpy, mathematical-optimization

I have a loss function I would like to try and minimize:

```
def lossfunction(X,b,lambs):

    B = b.reshape(X.shape)

    penalty = np.linalg.norm(B, axis = 1)**(0.5)

    return np.linalg.norm(np.dot(X,B)-X) + lambs*penalty.sum()
```

Gradient descent, or similar methods, might be useful.  I can't calculate the gradient of this function analytically, so I am wondering how I can numerically calculate the gradient for this loss function in order to implement a descent method.

Numpy has a `gradient` function, but it requires me to pass a scalar field at pre determined points.

Answer (score 1):

You could try [scipy.optimize.minimize](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.optimize.minimize.html)
For your case a sample call would be:

```
  import scipy.optimize.minimize
  scipy.optimize.minimize(lossfunction, args=(b, lambs), method='Nelder-mead')
```

Answer (score 0):

You could estimate the derivative numerically by a [central difference](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Finite_difference#Forward.2C_backward.2C_and_central_differences):

```
def derivative(fun, X, b, lambs, h):
    return (fun(X + 0.5*h,b,lambs) - fun(X - 0.5*h,b,lambs))/h
```

And use it like this:

```
# assign values to X, b, lambs
# set the value of h
h = 0.001
print derivative(lossfunction, X, b, lambs, h)
```

The code above is valid for dimX = 1, some modifications are needed to account for multidimensional vector X:

```
def gradient(fun, X, b, lambs, h):
    res = []
    for i in range (0,len(X)):
        t1 = list(X)
        t1[i] = t1[i] + 0.5*h
        t2 = list(X)
        t2[i] = t2[i] - 0.5*h
        res = res + [(fun(t1,b,lambs) - fun(t2,b,lambs))/h]
    return res
```

Forgive the naivity of the code, I barely know how to write some python :-)